# Powershell - Find and replace XML config data with Registry values

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, registry

I am currently trying to access the registry, obtain all the sub keys with it's appropriate values and then substitute these values with an XML config.

For example:

Within the XML document the following value is stored:

```
<Name = "Test" Value = "\\somelocation\TOKEN\Application" />
<Name = "Test1" Value = "\\somelocation\TOKEN\Deployment" />
```

The registry key holds the token value:

TOKEN= LifeCycleManagement

Therefore I want powershell to subsitute "\somelocation\TOKEN*" with "\somelocation\LifeCycleManagement*"

Any ideas please?

Currently I am trying the following code:

```
$lineElement = @()

$regItems = Get-ItemProperty registrylocation
Get-ItemProperty registrylocation > c:\DEV\output.txt
$contents = Get-Content c:\DEV\output.txt

foreach ($line in $contents)
{
    $line = $line -split(":")
    $lineElement += $line[0]
}

foreach ($element in $lineElement)
{
    $element
    $regItems.$element
}
```

The $regItems.$element is not returning any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, typically a `$line` will initially typically look like this:

`Token........: LifeCycleManagement`. When you split your line at `:` and take the first part you will get `Token.........` (the `.`'s are spaces). Obviously `$regItems.Token.........` is not what you are after. You should get rid of the spaces at the end of your `$line`. This can be done using `Trim()`. The example code below will fix your issue.

```
$lineElement = @()

$regItems = Get-ItemProperty registrylocation
Get-ItemProperty registrylocation > c:\DEV\output.txt
$contents = Get-Content c:\DEV\output.txt

foreach ($line in $contents)
{
    $line = $line -split(":")
    $lineElement += ($line[0]).Trim()
}

foreach ($element in $lineElement)
{
    $element
    $regItems.$element
}
```